# JavaScript: object values differ when using them inside a clojure

Tags: javascript, arguments, call, apply, debouncing

I have a function called `.debounce()` which is useful to put a delay before triggering an event's callback [(More info)](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function).

```
debounce = function( fn, delay, args ) {

    var id;

    if ( !fn || !delay )
        throw new Error( '`fn` and `delay` have to be provided.' );

    return function( e ) {

        if ( !args )
            args = arguments;

        var newFn = function() {

                // problem is here:
                // ================
                // args[ 0 ].deltaY != e.deltaY
                // two values above aren't equal
                // which should be!

                fn.apply( ctx, args );

            },

            ctx = this;

        clearTimeout( id );

        id = setTimeout( newFn, delay );

    }


}
```

I'm using `.apply()` method to pass `arguments` object to actual `fn` which is passed by the developer to `.debounce` function. It's working, but the values of that event are messing up!

When I use `e.deltaY` it's returning correct value, but `args[ 0 ].deltaY` always returns 1.

P.S.

It's a hard question to ask, but I'm using that debounce like this:

```
element.addEventListener( 'wheel', debounce( scrolled, 50 ) );
```

I'm using this `.debounce` function for a long time and never had a similar problem. I don't know what is wrong with me ( or this event! ).

I've made a [live version of the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/j350x984/) which will `console.log()` two values each time you try to scroll. first one used `.apply` method and the second one used `.call`.

I have no idea what's happening!

**Edit**: I'm not looking for a solution, because as soon as I change `fn.apply( ctx, args );` to `fn.call( ctx, e );` problem is solved. I want to know what and how is it happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the

```
if ( !args )
    args = arguments;
```

part which initialises the `args` variable only once - when the function is called for the first time. The scope of `args` and `e` is different, `e` is local to the function where `newFn` is created but `args` persists across calls. So one way calls your `fn` with the first event that was passed to the debounced function and the other way calls it with the last scroll event - this is what you want. To do that, you'll want to remove the condition, or even make `args` local as well:

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
//                         ^ no "default" (?) args here
    var id;
    if (!fn || !delay)
        throw new Error('`fn` and `delay` have to be provided.');
    return function(e) {
        var args = arguments,
//      ^^^
            ctx = this;

        function newFn() {
            fn.apply(ctx, args);
        }

        clearTimeout(id);
        id = setTimeout(newFn, delay);
    };
}
```

Alternatively, you may simply do `var newFn = Function.prototype.apply.bind(fn, this, arguments);`.

Comment: Would you please explain a bit more? I'm not sure if I understand what have you meant correctly.